# How can I access attributes using camel case?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, naming-conventions

To be consistent over my coding style, I'd like to use `camelCase` to access attributes instead of `snake_case`. Is this possible in Laravel without modifying the core framework? If so, how?

Example:

```
// Database column: first_name

echo $user->first_name; // Default Laravel behavior
echo $user->firstName; // Wanted behavior
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Create your own `BaseModel` class and override the following methods. Make sure all your other models `extend` your `BaseModel`.

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class BaseUser extends User
{
    public function getAttribute($key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations)) {
            return parent::getAttribute($key);
        } else {
            return parent::getAttribute(Str::snake($key));
        }
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value) {
        return parent::setAttribute(Str::snake($key), $value);
    }
}
```

Then for usage:

```
// Database column: first_name

echo $user->first_name; // Still works
echo $user->firstName; // Works too!
```

This trick revolves around forcing the key to snake case by overriding the magic method used in `Model`.

Comment: You also have to extend __isset() and __unset() methods. Otherwise isset(), empty() and unset() functions will not work properly with camel case keys. I spent half a day on this bug.

Comment: Is this also possible as trait?

Answer (score 22):

Since SO doesn't allow pasting code snippets in comments, I'm posting this as a new answer.

To make sure that eager loading does not break, I had to modify @Lazlo's answer. When accessing eagerly loaded relations by a different key, they are reloaded.

```
<?php

class BaseModel extends Eloquent
{

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations)) {
            return parent::getAttribute($key);
        } else {
            return parent::getAttribute(snake_case($key));
        }
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        return parent::setAttribute(snake_case($key), $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the issue that you solved here? i'm not really following that verification you do on the relations array?

Comment: let's say you run the query ``User::with('likedPosts')``, it will be stored as ``$user->attributes['likedPosts']``. However, when you override ``getAttribute`` and change everything into snake_case, then it would try to access ``$user->attributes['liked_posts']`` when you write ``$user->likedPosts``, which doesn't exist. Then laravel will lazy load the relationship, even though the relationship was already loaded (as likedPosts). To prevent this, the ``if`` statement is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Just thought I'd post this in case it helps anyone else. Though the entry by [Bouke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597065/bouke-versteegh) is great it does not address lazy-loaded relations that use a camel-case name. When this occurs we simply need to check for the method name in addition to the other checks. The following is what I did:

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent
{

    public function getAttribute($key)
    {

        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->relations)
          || method_exists($this, $key)
        )
        {
            return parent::getAttribute($key);
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::getAttribute(snake_case($key));
        }
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        return parent::setAttribute(snake_case($key), $value);
    }
}
```