# Laravel use dynamic mutators in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-5.1, mutators

So i have two columns - SizeX & SizeY. For front end users I use Laravel mutator

```
public function getSizeAttribute(){
    /**
     * Set Size
     */
    $size = $this->SizeX. " x ". $this->SizeY;
    /**
     * Return
     */
    return $size;
}
```

To format the sizes like this `SizeX x SizeY`. The column `Sizes` does not exists because its dynamic. Is it possible to use mutators or alternative within the Elaquent model to detect that this is a dynamic attribute, and use some sort of method to convert the `SizeX x SizeY` to individual columns? Once the user submits the attribute `Size` back to laravel application for filtering?

Edit:

Right, this is the method I'm using to retrieve filtered Items

```
public function scopeFilteredMaterials($query,$params = array()){ 
    /**
     * Get filters
     */
    $filters = array();
    /**
     * Extract Info
     */
    if(!empty($params) && is_array($params)){
        /**
         * Get Available Filters
         */
        $filters = $this->getAvailableFilters();

        foreach ($filters as $key => $filter){
            if(isset($params[$filter])){

                $filters[$filter] = $params[$filter];

                unset($filters[$key]);
            }else{

                unset($filters[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($filters as $key => $filter){

        $query->whereIn(key ,$filter);
    }

    $result = $query->get();
}
```

This is the filters variable which holds available filters for user to see

`protected $filters = array(
        "Name",
        "url",
        "Size",
    );`

I'm using the above to show the specific values to the user. Once the user selects those values I'm using the same array to check against those filters and fire the query. My problem is the `Size` attribute is made up of two columns which I have not problem using the following Mutator and `$appends` variable to automatically bring the value to the user.

```
/**
 * Get Size Attribute
 */
public function getSizeAttribute(){
    /**
     * Set Size
     */
    $size = $this->SizeX. " x ". $this->SizeY;
    /**
     * Return
     */
    return $size;
}
```

But i ca't figure out a way to convert the `Size` variable back to `SizeX` & `SizeY`

Answer (score 2):

If you are always creating the composite variable through the accessor, then you can use a scope that parses this string. Something like this:

```
public function scopeSize($query, $size)
{
    $sizes = explode(' x ', $size);
    return $query->where('SizeX',  $sizes[0])->where('SizeY', $sizes[1]);
}
```

You can then use this scope in the filter method or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new dynamic attribute, just create an accessor:

```
public function getSizesAttribute()
{
    return $this->SizeX . ' x ' . $this->SizeY;
}
```

If you want to set `SizeX` and `SizeY` automatically in case if `Sizes` property exists. In this case, you can create [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) for both `SizeX` and `SizeY`. For example:

```
public function setSizeXAttribute($value)
{
    if (!empty($this->attributes['Sizes'])) {
        $this->attributes['SizeX'] = explode(' x ', $this->attributes['Sizes']))[0];
    }
}

public function setSizeYAttribute($value)
{
    if (!empty($this->attributes['Sizes'])) {
        $this->attributes['SizeY'] = explode(' x ', $this->attributes['Sizes']))[1];
    }
}
```

PS: This is a solution for standard snake_case properties, like `size_x`. I'd really recommend you to use these in Laravel. If you still want to use `SizeX`, you should also [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559558/how-can-i-access-attributes-using-camel-case).

Comment: Wouldn't I have to explicitly say update SizeX for setSizeXAttribute method to be invoked?

Comment: Well, it definitely works when you explicitly update it with something like `$model->attribute = $value;`. I'm trying to not use mutators, but as far as I remember, it also works when you creating a model with `create()` or similar methods.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant was wouldn't i have todo something like : $query->where("SizeX","200"); for setSizeXAttribute method to be invoked? If lets say I have  $query->where("Sizes","200 x 300"); would it be possible to invoke the setSizeXAttribute & setSizeYAttribute methods? Or alternatively invoke some sort of setSizesAttribute which would search for the SizeX & SizeY columns based on setSizeXAttribute & setSizeYAttribute methods?

Comment: In this case, I'd do something like ` $query->where('SizeX', 200)->where('SizeY', 300)`. It's the best way to handle this.

Comment: haha yeah I thought about it, but I have an array of filters, and one of them uses two columns so I was wondering if I can be clever about this and avoid using those...

Comment: @Vilius I don't see a problem here. If you want to make it readable, use a scope (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes). If you want to do a lot of other `where()` and `orWhere()`, you can wrap it in a `where()` closure (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping).

Comment: I dont think scopes would solve this problem here as there would be other search variables. So i would have to write a scopes for each search filter for the loop to be able to access which defeats the purpose of this exercise...

Comment: Scopes are just for readability. I don't see a problem here. Could you show the query code and explain what exactly are you worried about?

Comment: @Vilius Thanks. I don't see a problem here. For sizes you can just use a `where()` closure or use where like this `where(['SizeX' => 200, 'SizeY' => 300])`.