# Camel Case Model Property to match Database Table

Tags: php, database

I have a weird question. Inside my database table, all the attributes are named with **underscore**. For this example I’ll take my Cart table, which has **cart_id, customer_id, is_ordered, order_date** columns.

After I run my SQL Statement (I am fetching inside class), I want to display the output to View (trough Controller), but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property Eshop\Model\CartModel::$cartId must not be accessed before initialization
```

But as soon as I **change** the the **properties** inside Cart Model **to** **match** the **database** table (with underscore), it **works** perfectly!

Cart Model Properties (Underneath are getter and setters)

```
class CartModel
{
    private int    $cartId;
    private int    $customerId;
    private int    $isOrdered;
    private string $orderDate;
    private array  $cartItem;
```

How can I solve this problem, while leaving model's property CamelCase, and Database columns with underscore? Thanks for help!

## SOLUTION

Instead PDO::Fetch Class I fetched manually inside Class (Model)

```
//Repository
 $rows = $statement->fetchAll();
 $container=[];
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $cartModel = new CartModel();
            $cartModel->setCartId($row['cart_id']);
            $cartModel->setIsOrdered($row['is_ordered']);
            $cartModel->setOrderDate($row['order_date']);
            $container[]=$cartModel;
        }
        return $container;
```

## Solution 2

To SQL Statement add "AS" keyword

```
SELECT customer_id AS customerid FROM cart WHERE cart_id=63;
```

Comment: there are probably annotations to use with your ORM

Comment: PHP has no clue that `cartId` should be equal to `cart_id` unless it's told so somehow. As far as PHP is concerned, those are simply two different properties. Either use the same format in both PHP and the DB, or add some magic __get()-function that takes the camel case, converts it to snake case (google this an you'll find some ready solutions) and return that property, if it exists. I'm guessing that you already have some __get() function or similar since all properties are private?

Comment: Instead PDO::FETCH_CLASS, I've set the properties manually using setters (I've provided a solution). But to answer you, I didn't used magic methods because it can be very messy. I used my own getters and setters. Thanks @M.Eriksson for help tho!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access attributes using camel case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559558/how-can-i-access-attributes-using-camel-case)

Comment: As well, it is possible to add "AS" keyword to SQL statement, so we have control there how we want to name our output.

Comment: I got my solution already. Maar toch bedankt! :) @RonvanderHeijden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION 1

Instead PDO::Fetch Class I fetched manually inside Class (Model)

```
//Repository
 $rows = $statement->fetchAll();
 $container=[];
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $cartModel = new CartModel();
            $cartModel->setCartId($row['cart_id']);
            $cartModel->setIsOrdered($row['is_ordered']);
            $cartModel->setOrderDate($row['order_date']);
            $container[]=$cartModel;
        }
        return $container;
```

## Solution 2

To SQL Statement add "AS" keyword

```
SELECT customer_id AS customerid FROM cart WHERE cart_id=63;
```